# GridView Items Not of Uniform Size

Tags: android, gridview

Hi guys I have Written a custom Gridview, However my Issue here is that each single item of them is occupying different height and this has caused alignment issues also looks ugly, I don't want to hard code the height that each individual item should occupy, I wonder if this can be done more efficient. I cannot Post the Image with to illustrate the issue as i need reputation in any case

The Xml Code that i have used which is causing this Mayhem i.e., the grid View

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/inboxView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#d3d3d3"
android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
android:numColumns="2"
 >

</GridView>
```

and the Code for each GridItem

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="8dp"
android:background="#fff"
 >


<!-- Image -->
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="@drawable/default_view" />


<!-- Date  -->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/date"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:padding="2dp"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:textSize="@dimen/date_info" />

<!-- Cricketer Name -->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:layout_below="@id/date"
    android:textSize="@dimen/name"        
    android:textColor="#00B0F0" />

<!-- Patient Mobile Number -->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/contact"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/title"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:textSize="@dimen/mobile"
    android:textColor="#00B0F0" />

<!-- Short Info -->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/shortInfo"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/contact"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:textSize="@dimen/short_info" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using Height of Relative Layout as wrap_content so height of Grid item depend on your Item like image height and textview height

Comment: I do not want to set the height of the layout to a specific value, I am aware this would help resolve the issue

Comment: Naveen i have updated the code to have a fill_parent height like you suggested but doesn't help

Answer (score 0):

Fixing the size of relative layout helps:

```
RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="100dp" // 100dp is just an example
android:layout_height="100dp"
android:padding="8dp"
android:background="#fff"
 >
```